# How can I reduce searching over an Array if I need to access the array elements multiple times?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, hashtable

I used an ArrayList of 10 elements in my code. I have to search it repeatedly over the time my code runs. Its an ArrayList of objects and I have to access and modify various aspects of that object.
In theory, I am suppose to search it once in a cycle. While implementing I end up searching 5 times a cycle. How can I reduce it? I thought of hashing but hashing does not provide much freedom playing with the object elements.

Comment: If you want a data structure which doesn't have a big penalty for many accesses, then using a `Map` of some sort might be helpful.  And yes, please post your code.

Comment: If there is no more than 10 elements ever, I wouldn't really bother optimise it. Looping through 10 elements is not very costly.

Comment: "I thought of hashing but hashing does not provide much freedom playing with the object elements" did not get meaning of this statement. Please clearly state your problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. it is a 600 lines code. that is why, i just asked the problem. it is an expert system. this is just an example where the set consists of 10 elements which may grow to 10k to 20k with 10/12 sub-element each. in that case the size matters. it is list of rules which are objects by themselves with various attributes. I have to work with those attributes by finding the rule in the set. that is why I have to search the set frequently to find that particular rule the situation demands. since I have to do this search frequently, how can I optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, searching through just 10 elements is already very efficient. For example, Clojure implements hashmaps up to 16 elements with a plain array.

If you plan to expand the list, then you can improve on linear search by defining a *lookup key*, which will be used in a hashtable. You can mutate the *values* in the hashtable as much as you like, and you can even mutate the key object as long as it doesn't change the fields contributing to its equality definition.

Comment: I used hash table instead. there was a decrease in elapsed time by 70.67%.

Comment: Just make sure you didn't use the `Hashtable` class.

Comment: I used it! Why may I ask?

Comment: Because it's legacy. Use `HashMap`.

Comment: Hi @Marko, the data in my HashMap are objects of type Rule. now I need to get it out and access those attributes in Rule object. I have created another object of type rule and trying to assign the values found by HashMap.get(key).thevalueIwant. HashMap.get(key) suppose to return me a rule. but compiler saying there is a type mismatch. why? it is not even identifying the class method. Any suggestion?

Comment: You probably need to take a look at Java Generics.